# Read-only access to file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/ with Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I need to check if a given permission (access to gallery on iOS) is granted, before executing a portion of code, but I did’t find what API to use. Can you help me?

My use case is to list the content of file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/ directory (in particular accessing to the “APPLExxx” subdirectories) using the FileSystemStorage API, but my code fails. I suppose that I need the gallery permissions, but I don’t know how to check/require them. Thank you

Underground problem: I wrote a native interface to access the gallery content, but I hate my native code, it’s a mess and it’s bugged/unusable, that why I trying to do the same task using a simpler cleaner approach, that is to try to access to the “dcim” directory with an high level API like FileSystemStorage. I only need to read the content (photos and videos), I don’t need to write (I know that I cannot write in that directory without low level APIs).

Thank you for suggestions and code examples.

Comment: Can't you just wrap each one of these two blocks in a native interface: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263344/ios-stopped-asking-user-for-photo-library-permission ?